# RedCap repeated instrument ASI (Automatic Invitation)

Tags: redcap

We are tracking participants' appointments with repeated instruments (appointment tracker and attendance tracker)

Appointment tracker would document their appointment date, and attendance tracker will be a survey sent on the appointment date to provider to verify if participants had attended or rescheduled etc. Because the attendance sequence matters (session 1, 2, etc.) we have multiple events and the attendance tracker to be a repeated instrument for each of this session events. (If a respondent didn't attend the first scheduled session 1 and rescheduled, we will send out another attendance tracker on the rescheduled session 1). Our ASI condition is whenever last appointment date is today (this last appointment date is documented at the appointment tracker, another repeated instruments)

it seems that RedCap can only allow multiple invites to be scheduled based on a time interval (e.g. every 5 days) not whenever the conditions are met again so that if we want to send out a second invite for the attendance tracker on that rescheduled date we can only do so manually?